# xmlhttprequest responseText returning blank

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, xmlhttprequest

I'm posting my form data to a google spreadsheet (it's working, I just can't get a response back) and am trying to return the values that were sent. The spreadsheet has 3 headers - name, image, result. Whenever I send the form data, I can write the values to the spreadsheet under the correct headers, I just can't get a responseText or statusText or anything like that back. How would I go about returning and console.logging the values?

[index.js]

```
var form = document.createElement('form'),
    node = document.createElement('input');
form.method = 'POST';
form.action = 'google apps script url';
form.style.display = 'none';

var params = {'name': name, 'image': image, 'result': result};

for (key in params)
{
  node.name = key;
  node.value = params[key];
  form.appendChild(node.cloneNode());
}

document.getElementById('formContainer').appendChild(form);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open(form.method, form.action, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send('name=' + name + '&image=' + image + '&result=' + result);
console.log(xhr.responseText); //returns blank...same w/ status / statusText / etc
document.getElementById('formContainer').removeChild(form);
```

[google apps script]

```
function doPost(e)
{
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;

  var row = [];

  for (i in headers)
  {
    row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
  }

  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);

  return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow, 'values': e.parameter}))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making an asynchronous request by setting the async parameter as true  [`xhr.open(form.method, form.action, true);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open). This means the code doesn't wait for a response from the webpage and proceeds to next line thus has an empty `xhr.responseText`

You will have to use the [`XMLHttpRequest.onload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onload) function to define the callback function. This will be executed when the response from the web application is received, like so

```
xhr.onload = function() {
           console.log(xhr.responseText);
        };
```

Your code would look like this :

```
  xhr.open(method, action, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.onload = function() {
       console.log(xhr.responseText);
    };
  xhr.send('name=' + name + '&image=' + image + '&result=' + result);
```

More details on asynchronous and synchronous can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests).

**Note:** Synchronous calls have been [deprecated](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open()-method) for latest versions of Mozilla and Chrome. So it is advisable not to use them.